# Git - Pull dev and out-of-sync feature branch to new feature branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a new feature branch, say `feature-me` which is checked-out from dev branch. There is also another feature branch `feature-external` which is not in sync with `dev`.  When I do `git pull feature-external` on `feature-mine`, it overwrites the `dev` branch to have only `feature-external`'s past `dev` branch code.

```
feature-external              feature-me (want feature-external and dev code)
|                             |
------------------dev-----------
```

How do I do **git pull** on `feature-me` to have code frim both `dev` and `feature-external`

Comment: This is more of a question about `git merge`, because `pull` is basically `fetch` + `merge`. But I'm pretty sure `git merge` already does what you are asking by default, so I don't understand why you're seeing this behaviour. Could you create a minimal reproducible example using a single repo?

Answer (score 2):

Try and see if you reproduce the issue with:

```
 git fetch
 git switch feature-me
 git merge origin/feature-external
```

Another approach would be:

```
 git fetch
 git switch feature-me
 git rebase origin/feature-external
```

In order to relocate your `feature-me` branch on top of `feature-external` latest code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your `pull.rebase` config option set to `true`. You can check this by running :

```
git config pull.rebase
```

(if nothing is output, my guess was wrong ; if it outputs `1` or `true`, it is indeed turned on)

---

Instead of using `git pull`, you may run the two commands `git fetch` and `git merge` yourself :

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/feature-external
```